# boto3 python SetupAWS.py setup "aws configure"

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-cli, aws-iot

I am trying to setup AWS IoT esp32 msys2, I followed the instructions but cannot solve the problem to setup the policy, certificates using the following command:

```
python SetupAWS.py setup
```

But I get this error message, I have installed and setup AWS configuration

```
AWS not configured. Please run `aws configure`.
```

All the paths seem to be connection, but cannot work out what could be the problem.

Comment: The error is stating that you need to go through the aws CLI configuration (API Credentials and Config defaults). The cli configuration creates a "credentials" and "config" files in your dot files (IE: $HOME/.aws). You can install the aws-cli with pip ( `pip install aws-cli` ) Edit: You may need to use 'sudo' if you want to install the CLI globally

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, I had some problems installing the aws-cli, so I just removed and re-installed everything and now working through the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, I deleted everything and re-installed the complete developed suite including the AWS aws-cli tools.